# SQL Hierarchy Visualization

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-visualization

I have a following problem:

- There exists an entity called Branch.
- A branch may belong to another branch or may be a standalone branch.
- A parent branch may belong to another branch or may be the highest level branch.
- There may be a UP TO 4-5 levels of hierarchy.
- There are no loop hierarchies (that we know of as of right now).

I am wanting to somehow export the data from SQL and visualize into some sort of tree looking diagram. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Here is a snapshot of my data model. Note that when DivisonParentBranch = RegionParentBranch = Branch, this implies that branch is standalone.

```
DivisionParentBranch RegionParentBranch Branch
                 150                401    401
                 150                401    402
                 150                401    403
                 150                401    404
                 273                248    248
                 273                248    277
                 273                248    278
                 273                273    273
                 273                273    286
                 273                273    408
                 273                273    809
                 356                356    356
                 356                356    358
                 356                356    363
                 356                356    405
                 356                356    773
                 356                357    357
                 356                361    361
                 356                361    364
                 739                511    511
                 739                511    513
                 739                511    514
                 739                511    515
                 739                511    517
                 739                511    519
                 739                511    520
                 739                511    779
```

[image]

## UPDATE:

Expected Result is to visualize these branch hierarchies. Something along the lines of the below image. We have around 500+ branches so need to automate this somehow.
[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images. BTW, can you add the expected result too, having that table data?

Comment: @jarlh added the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh converted data snapshot image to text

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty and I am sure someone do better using the GROUP BY ROLLUP function but starting with the output of this you could loop through the results set and build a display based on the hierarchy from the select below. Level 1 would be the topmost part of the tree, level 2 would link to level 1 and be the second row, etc.

Also, as mentioned in the comments please don't post 'data' as screen prints.

```
SELECT  div_branch, null as reg_branch, null as branch, '1' as level
FROM    @bracnhes
GROUP   BY div_branch
union all 
SELECT  div_branch, reg_branch, null as branch, '2' as level
FROM    @bracnhes
GROUP   BY div_branch, reg_branch
union all 
SELECT  div_branch, reg_branch, branch, '3' as level
FROM    @bracnhes
GROUP   BY div_branch, reg_branch, branch
```

My output, at least the little bit I bothered to test with looks like this

```
div_branch  reg_branch  branch  level
150         NULL        NULL        1
273         NULL        NULL        1
356         NULL        NULL        1
150         150         NULL        2
150         401         NULL        2
273         248         NULL        2
273         273         NULL        2
356         356         NULL        2
356         357         NULL        2
356         361         NULL        2
150         150         150         3
150         150         151         3
150         150         153         3
150         150         154         3
150         150         961         3
```

Comment: This answer shows 150 three times, which makes the data duplicated. 150 should only be represented once as it is a "Top Level".

Comment: Doesn't this answer only limits the tree to 3 levels? There are cases that go up to 4 levels for instance consider the following rows:  178, 177, 170 and 187,186,178 => this indicates that branch 170 belongs to 177 which belongs to 178 which belongs to 186 which belongs to 187. The naming is slightly ambiguous since one branch can be listed as "branch" in one row while "DivisionParentBranch" in another row.

Comment: What are the rules that define how these rows and columns relate to each other? Is Division Branch the parent of Region, and is Region the parent of Branch? 

The second row appears to violate the parent child relationship defined by your tree image?

Comment: So we have acquired this code/db so we are also trying to find it out too. What we have received from previous guys was that it was supposed to be 3 level only tree but then they realized they had more so they start adding new rows so I believe the best naming in here would be: Parent instead of RegionalParentBranch and GrandParent instead of DivisionalParentBranch.

Comment: I don't see how the three columns can be combined to form a set of parent child relationships that is more then 3 levels deep? Also what is the meaning of a row like this 150 | 150 | 150? What type of relationship does this define?

Comment: For the 'nested past 3 levels' are you trying to use something like 150 | 401 | 402 for the first set of hierarchical relations and then somehow use a row like 401 | 402 | 699, somehow determine that 401 is not a new parent but the continuation of a child from another hierarchy?

Comment: yeah I can see how this is kinda confusing. i am giong to update my question to cover different possibilities in data and what that case resembles. Please allow me a little bit of time to gather all the cases. I will also upload a CSV to get a full picture of the data